# Spring Integration SFTP: Create outbound gateway with parameter from a message header

Tags: spring-integration-sftp

I'm trying to implement a workflow where files from multiple SFTP sources get handled by the same integration flow.
Now, it works out alright in the beginning:

- I can list the files in the SFTP source, using a different SFTP session factory for each SFTP source (SFTP_DEDUPED_FILES_0, SFTP_DEDUPED_FILES_1).
- I can forward the message with the file name to a single channel (SFTP_FILES_CHANNEL).
- I can process the information about the file (FILE_PROCESSING_FLOW).

Now, here's the catch: I want to delete the source file after processing.
For this, I need the right session factory again.

**I already stored the SessionFactory in a message header - I just can't seem to extract it in order to create an outbound gateway for the delete call.**
How can I implement `deleteTheFile()`?

```
@Bean(SFTP_DEDUPED_FILES_0)
public IntegrationFlow getDedupedFilesFromSftp(List<SftpConnectionInfo> connectionInfos) {
    return createSftpGetFlow(connectionInfos.get(0));
}

@Bean(SFTP_DEDUPED_FILES_1)
public IntegrationFlow getDedupedFilesFromSftp1(List<SftpConnectionInfo> connectionInfos) {
    return createSftpGetFlow(connectionInfos.get(1));
}

private IntegrationFlow createSftpGetFlow(SftpConnectionInfo connectionInfo) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(PROVIDE_POLL_FREQUENCY)
            .handle(listRemoteFiles(connectionInfo.sessionFactory(), connectionInfo.dedupingKeyPrefix(), connectionInfo.sftpRemotePath()))
            .split()
            .enrichHeaders(addFilePathMessageHeader(connectionInfo.sftpRemotePath()))
            .enrichHeaders(addSessionFactoryMessageHeader(connectionInfo.sessionFactory()))
            .channel(SFTP_FILES_CHANNEL)
            .get();
}

@Bean(SFTP_FILES_CHANNEL)
public SubscribableChannel sftpFilesChannel() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
}

@Bean(FILE_PROCESSING_FLOW)
public IntegrationFlow sftpGetFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(SFTP_FILES_CHANNEL)
            .log(logTheFilePath())
            .log(logTheMessageHeaders())
            .handle(deleteTheFile())
            .get();
}

private SftpOutboundGatewaySpec listRemoteFiles(SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sessionFactory, String dedupingKeyPrefix, String sftpRemotePath) {
    return Sftp.outboundGateway(sessionFactory, LS, asExpression(sftpRemotePath))
            .options(RECURSIVE, NAME_ONLY)
            .filter(onlyFilesWeHaveNotSeenYet(dedupingKeyPrefix))
            .filter(onlyFiles());
}
```

---

**What implementations of `deleteTheFile()` I tried:**

This implementation seems to do something, but I don't want to create a new gateway every time, maybe there is a better solution.

```
private MessageHandler deleteTheFile() {
    return message -> {
        SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sessionFactory = (SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>) message.getHeaders().get(CUSTOM_HEADER_SESSION_FACTORY);
        SftpOutboundGatewaySpec gatewaySpec = Sftp.outboundGateway(sessionFactory, RM, "headers['" + CUSTOM_HEADER_REMOTE_FILE + "']");
        gatewaySpec.get().handleMessage(message);
    };
}
```

Plus, it's not a proper bean, so I guess that's why it fails and throws an exception:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: No beanFactory
        at org.springframework.integration.expression.ExpressionUtils.createStandardEvaluationContext(ExpressionUtils.java:90) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
        at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.getEvaluationContext(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:111) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
        at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.getEvaluationContext(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
        at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:169) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
        at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor.processMessage(ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor.java:109) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.obtainRemoteFilePath(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:760) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.doRm(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:709) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:592) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
        at com.example.sftp.incoming.SftpMergedIncomingRecursiveConfiguration.lambda$deleteTheFile$4(SftpMergedIncomingRecursiveConfiguration.java:136) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: I tried to reduce the code to what is essential here - it's already quite long. If you think you need the concrete implementations of some of the methods, I can easily add them, of course.

Comment: Currently, as a workaround, I create full workflows for each connection (i.e., there is no intermediate `SFTP_FILES_CHANNEL` channel), but I wonder if it can be done differently.